# is it possible to control additional buttons of the mouse in jQuery

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I know that jQuery can handle the mouse clicks events (left/right/middle)

But one of my clients has 5 buttons.

And he really wants me to capture that events too.
I checked the jQuery manual http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/
but was not able to find how to achieve this.

Is it possible?

P.S by additional buttons on the mouse I mean something like that:

1. [mouse 1](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5d/Mouse_buttons.svg/282px-Mouse_buttons.svg.png)
2. [mouse 2](http://www.promo-wholesale.com/Upfiles/Prod_l/Mini-Wireless-Optical-5-button-Mouse_20090804594.jpg)

Comment: I cant find anything regard to this. Everywhere they have right left and middle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot.

Some browsers will map the buttons on the side of the mouse to browser "back" and "forward" actions. You can't exactly trap these actions, nor can you map these buttons to different actions. If your site uses the [HTML5 history API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html), you can create multiple history entries and do something when the user navigates to different states, but you cannot introduce new behavior beyond this.

If browsers don't handle these buttons, they are ignored entirely, and there's nothing your site can do about it.